# Good or Bad: 'where 1=1' in sql condition

Tags: sql

Why would someone use `WHERE 1=1 AND <conditions>` in a SQL claus.
I don't understand why would someone use this construction for defining a view, or use it inside a stored procedure.

for example:

```
select * from user where 1=1
```

Comment: That seems totally not useful, since `select * from user` would return the same results.

Comment: I've not seen it - I would look forward to anyone who can explain.

Comment: I've used it when I'm doing some data analysis and I want to quickly add and comment out other filter conditions that follow in subsequent lines.

Comment: I've also used it - if you don't know whether there will be any conditions or their order until runtime  it can simplify the generating code. It always feels a bit "hacky" though.